# root.destroy does not terminate threads running in shell

Tags: python, multithreading, shell

I am trying to close my application in the correct manner but i may not be doing this correctly and what i have does not seem to fit the requirement.

I have the normal

```
command = root.destroy
```

which closes the GUI but i still have threads running which seem to keep going evident in the printing in Shell!

Below is the thread that is 'immortal'

```
def trick(threadName, sleepTime):
    while 1 < 2:
         field.delete(0, END)
         field.insert(0, "Safe Mode")
         print "%s" % (threadName)
try:
    thread.start_new_thread(trick,("Safe Mode Running", 5))
except: Exception,
print "Safe mode has started"
```

I then have other parts and the GUI finishes like shown below:

```
Close = Button(text = "Close", command = root.destroy)
Close.grid(column = 21, row = 0)        

root.configure(background='#2b5bce')
root.title("Safe Mode")
root.mainloop()
```

Where am I going wrong?

Thank you in advance.

p.s. It's a sunny day here in London!

Answer (score 1):

First, you should use the [`threading`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/threading.html) module instead of the `thread` module, as suggested in [the docs](https://docs.python.org/2/library/thread.html) for the `thread` module:

> **Note:** The thread module has been renamed to _thread in Python 3. The 2to3
>   tool will automatically adapt imports when converting your sources to
>   Python 3; **however, you should consider using the high-level `threading`
>   module instead.**

That said, there are a couple of options to solve your issue:

One is to use a `threading.Thread` object and set it to be a [daemonic thread](https://docs.python.org/2/library/threading.html#threading.Thread.daemon):

```
def trick(threadName, sleepTime):
    while 1 < 2:
         field.delete(0, END)
         field.insert(0, "Safe Mode")
         print "%s" % (threadName)
try:
    t = threading.Thread(target=trick, args=("Safe Mode Running", 5))
    t.daemon = True
    t.start()
except: Exception,
print "Safe mode has started"
```

daemon threads will exit when your main thread finishes. Non-daemon threads (which are the default type in Python), will continue to run even after the main thread has completed, and your program won't quit until the non-daemon threads exit on their own.

The second option is use non-daemon threads, but tell them to shut down when the program is ready to exit:

```
exiting = threading.Event()

def trick(threadName, sleepTime):
    while 1 < 2:
         if exiting.is_set():
             return
         field.delete(0, END)
         field.insert(0, "Safe Mode")
         print "%s" % (threadName)
try:
    t = threading.Thread(target=trick, args=("Safe Mode Running", 5))
    t.daemon = True
    t.start()
except: Exception,
print "Safe mode has started"
```

Then in your main thread:

```
Close = Button(text = "Close", command = root.destroy)
Close.grid(column = 21, row = 0)        

root.configure(background='#2b5bce')
root.title("Safe Mode")
root.mainloop()
exiting.set()  # Tell the threads to exit
```

This has the advantage of letting you close down the thread gracefully. Using `daemon=True` will immediately terminate your threads, which could potentially be bad if they're in the middle of something (eg. writing something or holding some resource that won't automatically be released. The `threading` docs [make a note of this as well](https://docs.python.org/2/library/threading.html#thread-objects):

> Daemon threads are abruptly stopped at shutdown. Their resources (such
>   as open files, database transactions, etc.) may not be released
>   properly. If you want your threads to stop gracefully, make them
>   non-daemonic and use a suitable signalling mechanism such as an Event.